# Missing (str.to-int s) in Z3 4.5.1

Tags: string, z3, smt

I'm using Z3 4.5.1 successfully with strings and operations such as sub-string, string-length, string-comparisons etc. like this example:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)
(declare-const i Int)
(assert (= s1 "97\x00098\x0099###$$"))
(assert (= s2 (str.substr s1 2 (- (str.len s1) 2))))
(assert (= "\x00058\x0099###$$" (str.replace s2 "9" "5")))
(check-sat)
(get-value (s1 s2 i))
```

However, when I try to add **str.to-int**:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)
(declare-const i Int)
(assert (= s1 "97\x00098\x0099###$$"))
(assert (= s2 (str.substr s1 2 (- (str.len s1) 2))))
(assert (= "\x00058\x0099###$$" (str.replace s2 "9" "5")))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(assert (= 98 (str.to-int "000098")))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(check-sat)
(get-value (s1 s2 i))
```

I get this error:

```
(error "line 8 column 35: unknown function/constant str.to-int")
```

I'm puzzled because "to-int" appears in the documentation along other
string operations that are all working perfectly. I'm using this documentation: [Z3str3 Input Language](https://zyh1121.github.io/z3str3Docs/inputLanguage.html#input-language-summary). Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 has been using str.to.int and int.to.str for a while. The SMTLIB2 format for strings hasn't been finalized at this point either.